# Remove image from view page after deleting with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on asp.net mvc3 application with razor view. The business logic I must implement is more complicated than my answer but as you can guess my knowledge on JS/jQuery is very poor so I take this step by step.

From the controller I get a list with all the pictures I have to show in my view and then display them like this :

```
@foreach (var image in ViewBag.DocumentPicture)
    {
        if (image != null)
        { 
            <img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\@image.Name" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePicture", new { documentImageID = image.Id },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                Confirm = "Are you sure?",
                //OnComplete = "$('#blah').attr('src', '#').attr('style', 'display:none;'); $('#Image1').attr('src', '#').attr('style', 'display:none;'); $('#DelPic').attr('style', 'display:none;');"
            })
        }
    }
```

I don't want to reload my entire view so I just want ti remove the image from the view once it's deletion is confirmed. I don't know if I could just make it `hidden` or something else would be better, but hope it's not that difficult of a task I just don't have much knowledge on JS/jQuery.

P.S

Here is the rendered HTML :

```
<div id="document-image-gallery">
<img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\10005\docPicTest1.jpg" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/Forms/DeletePicture?documentImageID=26">Delete</a>            
<img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\10005\docPicTest2.jpg" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/Forms/DeletePicture?documentImageID=27">Delete</a>            
<img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\10005\docPicTest3.jpg" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/Forms/DeletePicture?documentImageID=28">Delete</a>            
<img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\10005\docPicTest4.jpg" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/Forms/DeletePicture?documentImageID=29">Delete</a>            
<img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\10005\docPicTest5.jpg" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/Forms/DeletePicture?documentImageID=30">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the rendered HTML instead?

Comment: @Archer please see the updated post. The `P.S` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use a standard link:

```
@foreach (var image in ViewBag.DocumentPicture)
{
    if (image != null)
    {
        <div>
            <img src="file:///5.3.2.7/upload/@image.Name" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePicture", new { documentImageID = image.Id }, new { @class = "delete" })
        </div>
    }
}
```

that I would unobtrusively AJAXify:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'POST',
                context: this,
                success: function(result) {
                    $(this).closest('div').remove();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

This allows us to capture the link that was clicked inside the success callback of the AJAX request, find the closest containing div and remove it from the DOM. Obviously to avoid mixing HTML and markup it a real world application the javascript snippet shown in my answer should be placed in a separate js file that you could simply reference from your view.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There's a lot to learn from you. For now I just want to make it work. Actually in my controller I don't perform any action, I just collect the ID's in a List which I pass to a service, that's where my code ends. But I want to be able to remove the image from the view without reloading, this is the most important part here.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what my code does. It removes the corresponding `<img>` element from the DOM. The problem with the `Ajax.ActionLink` is that it is hard to get a reference to the link that was clicked inside the success callback and thus you do not know which image to remove. You have far greater control if you write the jQuery code yourself. And also it will allow you to learn it.

Comment: Nice, gonna try your way. Thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

In *CSHTML*

```
@foreach (var image in ViewBag.DocumentPicture)
{
    if (image != null)
    { 
        <img src="file:\\5.3.2.7\upload\@image.Name" alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePicture", new { documentImageID = image.Id },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            Confirm = "Are you sure?",
            OnComplete = "DeleteImage"
        })
    }
}
```

*JavaScript* function

```
function DeleteImage() {
   $(this).prev().remove(); //get previous sibling http://api.jquery.com/prev/
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but do I have to add something in the controller or the view because just like that the image is not remove?